# UIViewController pushed onto UIController embedded in UITabBarController not calling delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` that has four `UIViewControllers`. These are set up in the app delegate and everything behaves as expected.

I have set the first `UIViewController` as the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and that works fine too; as tabs are pressed `shouldShowViewController` fires as expected.

Inside the first `UIViewController`, the first tab, are buttons. One pushes another `UIViewController` using the standard:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

This works just fine: the new `UIViewController` and it's view appear as expected.

However, when I press the tab button the `shouldShowViewController` function is called (as expected) and passes a reference to the first tab (as expected) but the child `UIViewController` is nowhere to be found.  That is, `viewController.navigationController.viewControllers` is an empty array (`count == 0`).

To debug I implemented the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and assigned the navigationController to the same class from the `UIViewController` and tab controller. It fires when called from the tab controller but not the view controller.

I've tried everything I can think of to find a reference to the topmost visible view controller but I'm stumped; it seems to vanish into a black hole.  I"m ready to try to keep the stack manually but trying to keep a parallel array with system functionality built into it seems like a setup for a maintenance mess.  I am using iOS6.

Comment: It's kind of hard to grasp the whole picture based only on text description (hard to follow which `UIViewController` is which). Could you maybe post a picture of your storyboard if you have one or a quick schema of the controllers hierarchy (or at least assign letters/numbers to the controllers) ?

Comment: Hi- figured it out. Everything's being created programmatically so no storyboard.  Think of four tabs, the first one containing some number of viewcontroller's.  What I finally realized is when you press a tab once it will show the top controller.  When you press it twice it will pop to root: that's why there were no child viewcontrollers.  My problem is I had background processes running so couldn't have them popped off without problems.  I solved by putting a reference into a singleton.  If I had more rep I'd make an illustration to show; I'm surprised this doesn't confuse more people.